# How can I update adword-customizer data using google app script. (previously uploaded source are causing error)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I have over 500 customizer data files that needs to be pushed into google ads. I am looking at the scripting to automate this also update the customizer data regularly.

My files have these columns

`cityid,oemname, cityname, price, Target Location.`

Now out of those 500 files I have uploaded 2 files manually as testing.
Now when I am previewing the script I am getting

`Exception: Invalid argument: oemname`

this error is thrown only for the data source already uploaded in customizer.
please let me know how can I do this.

NOTE: My customizer files are located in google drive spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you add any details like code used? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Targets can not be changed. 
Like target location, target keywords, target campaign.
that's why i was getting error.